# Clicking on a different button doesn't allow me to click back on the original one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a jquery script which changes the css selector when I click on a specific button, well the script does work but I can't click back on the default selected button.

I've tried changing a few variables and other things but nothing works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-secondary").click(function() {
    $(".btn-primary").addClass('btn-secondary').removeClass('btn-primary');
    $(this).addClass('btn-primary').removeClass('btn-secondary');
  });
});
```

```css
.btn-primary { background-color: blue }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col text-center">
  <button class="btn mb-1 btn-primary" name="type" value="username">Username</button>
  <button class="btn mb-1 btn-secondary" name="type" value="email">Email</button>
  <button class="btn mb-1 btn-secondary" name="type" value="password">Password</button>
  <button class="btn mb-1 btn-secondary" name="type" value="hash">Hash</button>
  <button class="btn mb-1 btn-secondary" name="type" value="ip">IP Address</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That's because that button doesn't have the `btn-secondary` class when `document.ready` runs, so it doesn't get the event handler. Look into event delegation.

Comment: I just tried doing this
```html
                <button class="btn mb-1 btn-secondary btn-primary" name="type" value="username">Username</button>
```
And surprisingly it works, but is this a correct way to do it?

Comment: Depends on what your classes mean. It seems odd (to me) to have a button that is both the primary button and a secondary button, semantically speaking.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-secondary").click(function() {
    $(".btn-primary").addClass('btn-secondary').removeClass('btn-primary');
    $(this).addClass('btn-primary').removeClass('btn-secondary');
  });
});
```

In line 2 here, you are only adding the click listener to the 4 buttons with that className and *not* the first button (the one you want to reclick)

I would suggest changing this:

```
$(".btn-secondary").click(function() {
```

To this:

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
```

Example Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#buttons .btn").click(function() {
    $(".btn-primary").addClass('btn-secondary').removeClass('btn-primary');
    $(this).addClass('btn-primary').removeClass('btn-secondary');
  });
});
```

```css
.btn-primary { background-color: blue }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons" class="col text-center">
  <button class="btn mb-1 btn-primary" name="type" value="username">Username</button>
  <button class="btn mb-1 btn-secondary" name="type" value="email">Email</button>
  <button class="btn mb-1 btn-secondary" name="type" value="password">Password</button>
  <button class="btn mb-1 btn-secondary" name="type" value="hash">Hash</button>
  <button class="btn mb-1 btn-secondary" name="type" value="ip">IP Address</button>
</div>
```

Final edit: added ID to div element to localize jQuery call (prevent unintended spillover to other parts of the project)

Comment: Happy to help! I would also try to localize the jQuery call for when your project starts to get bigger. (right now the click listener will attach to _all_ elements with className "btn") 

Can you mark the solution for visibility?

Comment: Help this person get the green check! CHECK IT!